# Finding the name of a variable in a string and then replacing the variable name with the variable value

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a reference to a variable in a string (here: variable is var1)

I want to find `{var1}` in the sentence and replace it with the value for var1 ("testentry1")

Referring to var1 allows the desired string to be set

However, I can't do the same thing when referring to var_name

I will have a number of variable names *(e.g. `{var1}`, `{var2}`)* which will be in sentences and I'd like a way of substituting the appropriate word into the string.

```py
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "testentry1"
        self.var2 = "testentry2"


    def convert_text(self, original_text):
        #find the variable name of interest (here: {var1})
        found_text = re.findall('\{([^{}]*)\}', original_text)
        var_name = found_text[0]
        #replace {var1} with the value for var1
        search_str = "{"+var_name+"}"
        new_text = original_text.replace(search_str, self.var_name)
        new_text2 = original_text.replace(search_str, self.var1)

        print("output1 is (not desired result):", new_text)
        print("output2 is (desired result):", new_text2)
        return new_text2

TC = TestClass()



TC.convert_text("this is the text to change {var1}")
TC.convert_text("this is the text to change {var2}")
```

Comment: Use either a dictionary instead of plain variables (if this is a template system) or use a function instead of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stuff is built-in in python:

```
var1 = "testentry1"
print("this is the text to change {var1}".format(**locals()))
```

Note that it's usually better to use a dictionary to carry the context, rather than bare variables.

In case your strings are static (that is, you use them in the context where all variables are known beforehand), you can simply prepend a string with `f` (python 3.6+):

```
var1 = "testentry1"
print(f"this is the text to change {var1}")
```

If you really feel like reinventing wheels though, you can do the same with re's too:

```
def my_format(s, vars):
    return re.sub(r'{(\w+)}', lambda m: vars[m.group(1)], s)


print(my_format("this is the text to change {var1}", locals()))
```

"Automagic" replacement out-of-context (nonlocal) variables is also possible, but in a very hacky way:

```
# do NOT do that!

import re
import sys

var1 = "testentry1"


def my_format2(s):
    return re.sub(r'{(\w+)}', lambda m: eval(m.group(1)), s)


def get_var(name):
    f = sys._getframe()
    while f:
        if name in f.f_locals:
            return f.f_locals[name]
        f = f.f_back


def my_format3(s):
    return re.sub(r'{(\w+)}', lambda m: get_var(m.group(1)), s)


print(my_format2("this is the text to change {var1}"))
print(my_format3("this is the text to change {var1}"))
```

In response to your update, it's easy to use `format` with the class dict:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "testentry1"
        self.var2 = "testentry2"

    def convert_text(self, original_text):
        return original_text.format(**vars(self))


TC = TestClass()

print(TC.convert_text("this is the text to change {var1}"))
print(TC.convert_text("this is the text to change {var2}"))
```

Comment: I believe a dictionary is the better and less hacky way but this will work equally well :-)

Comment: @Bharel: sure, added a note about that.

Comment: This works to print the appropriate sentence outside of the function, but I can't set the value (new_text) within (var1 is set outside of the function so locals() isn't appropriate)

Comment: That's why you should use a dict for this, not variables. Of course, there's always `eval`, but I hope this is out of consideration.

Comment: How would I use a dict for it? If it makes any difference the variables are from a Class in reality (I've edited the question to show this)

Comment: @georg: that made it easier!